# Polynomial with given values over the natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Why is there for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and real numbers $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ a polynomial $p$ of maximal degree $n$ with $p(k)=a_k$ for every $1\leq k\leq n+1$?

I tried to prove this with induction but I have problems with the induction basis. Can somebody help please?

Does this theorem says something about questions of the type 'What is the next number in the sequence $1,3,5,7,9,...$?

Comment: For $n=1$ let $a_1,a_2$ we are looking for a polynomial $p(x)=nx+m$ so that $p(1)=a_1$ and $p(2)=a_2$ you have two equations in two variables
$$n+m = a_1$$
$$2n+m = a_2$$
Hence, $n=a_2-a_1$ and $m=2a_1-a_2$.

Comment: It is probably possible to prove for arbitrary $n$ (not by induction) you will get $n$ equations in $n$ variables and use linear algebra to deduce there exists a solution.

Comment: Look up Lagrange and Newton interpolation. The first gives the polynomial directly, the second lends itself to the iterative view.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- The matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&....... &1&1\\2^n&2^{n-1}&2^{n-2}&.......&2&1\\3^3&3^{n-1}&3^{n-2}&.......&3&1\\........\\(n+1)^n&(n+1)^n&(n+1)^{n-1}&.......&n+1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ has non-zero determinant so multiplied by the column $\{b_n,b_{n-1},b_{n-2},\cdots b_1,b_0\}$ gives univocally the vector column
$\{a_n,a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\cdots a_1,a_0\}$.

This gives the polynomial $p(x)=b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +b_1x+b_0$ with $p(k)=a_k$ for each $k$